# How to make a bold word on the text written for "help" command

Tags: matlab

If you type `help sin`, you'll notice that `sin` word is bold. How can I achieve this in my own function?

```
%
% If I write things here, they will compare as a result of "help" command
% How to make something bold?
%
function result = myfunction(...)

% ...

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working like this:

```
function testfun()
    % this is the testfun help text
end
```

Issueing `help testfun` will get you

> this is the testfun help text

But when you write `TESTFUN` in all upper case, i.e.

```
function testfun()
    % this is the TESTFUN help text
end
```

`help testfun` will display

> this is the **testfun** help text

Note that this only works for the name of the function, so changing "text" to "TEXT" will not make the word text bold. In addition, this only seems to work in the graphical version of Matlab.

some further reading: [Add Help for Your Program](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html)